# Converting US date format to UK date format

Tags: excel, vba, date-format

I have downloaded the coronovirus covid-19 time series dataset and need to convert the column headings in the .csv file to UK date format. I then want to set the column headings as a date axis on a graph to plot infection rates.

The dataset starts with 1/22/20, 1/23/20, then later changes to 02/01/2020, 02/02/2020, then changes to 2/13/20, 2/14/20 and then 03/01/2020, 03/02/2020. These are all M/D/Y.

I have written an Excel VBA macro which checks if the M value is 1 or 2 digits and adds a zero if 1 for consistency. As the text to column conversion still didn't work as expected, I then added to amend the year from 20 to 2020 to provide a consistent input dataset.

The code I am using is:

```
Sub usDateToUkDate()

    Dim r As Range
    Dim cells As Integer
    Dim cell As Range

    Set r = Range("E1", Range("E1").End(xlToRight))
    For Each cell In r
        cell.Select
        If Left(ActiveCell.Value, 1) <> 0 Then
            cell.Value = "0" & cell.Value
        End If
        If Len(ActiveCell.Value) <> 10 Then
            cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "20", "2020", 7)
        End If

        Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=ActiveCell(), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
            Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, OtherChar _
            :="/", FieldInfo:=Array(0, 3), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        ActiveCell.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Next cell
End Sub
```

While I don't fully understand the TextToColumns syntax as I copied a recorded macro, why am I getting inconsistent results. I did change the FieldInfo:=Array(1,3) to Array(0,3) as I wanted to start at the first character. The results I get are:
[Summary output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDSkt.png)

Dataset:  1/22/20
Output:   22 Jan 2020
Result:   Correct

Dataset:  02/01/2020
Output:   02 Jan 2020
Result:   Incorrect

The results repeat based on input format.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to convert dates from US to UK format?

Comment: Once the data is in Excel and you're running a macro on it, it's already attempted to change the dates to *your* regional settings. That can get really messy if it is date formatting, as it will ignore (not convert) data that doesn't conform to what it thinks a date is. So you can have columns that are only partially converted. Sometimes it is best to import the column as pure text and then convert it after.

Comment: @CLR - that's really helpful and really quick - thanks :-)
I guess I would be better off using Jupyter and Python to access the data, convert at .CSV level and then move into Power BI from there? I'm learning Python, but haven't got into the data analytics side of Jupyter labs yet, so I don't know how to model the dataset outside of Excel or Power BI.

Comment: It's certainly do-able using just VBA, but unless you share with us the exact method used to get  the data into Excel, it's hard to recommend a fix.

Comment: I have found the correct method for gathering a .CSV file from GitHub and pushing it into Excel.

Within GitHub, I found that if I go to the .CSV file and access the data, I can click on the Raw button, with the Option (Alt) key pressed and the file will be downloaded as .TXT. Within Excel, in Data, use the Get External Data section to import Text data. set the text to columns as comma separated first. Then select the columns that have a date as the column heading and adopt the Date function with MDY format. Finish then imports the text data with the column heading formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer - but got annoyed with Excel and the covid-19 files and resorted to other solution.
Viewing the file using gapminder.org as a visualizer.
Importing the data with a dirty tool I wrote: https://github.com/perolo/covid19togapminder